# Openssl support for ruby not found in passenger installation on redhat 6

Tags: ruby, openssl, passenger

I have openssl 1.0.1e-42.el6 already installed. Also tried to compile openssl from ext/openssl directory which failed with below error

```
ossl_pkey_ec.c:815: error: ‘EC_GROUP_new_curve_GF2m’ undeclared (first use in this function)
ossl_pkey_ec.c:815: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
ossl_pkey_ec.c:815: error: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [ossl_pkey_ec.o] Error 1
```

Is there any workaround for this problem ? or is this a compatibility problem with ruby 1.8.7-p358 and openssl 1.0.1e-42.el6. Due to this I am unable to install phusion passenger

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the above issue by applying the patch.

Refer link https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8384

You have to download the out.patch file to ruby source ext/openssl  folder and run `patch < out.patch` command. Then compile openssl